# Grammar for invertible functions

Tags: formal-grammars

Has anyone ever come up with a grammar that only induces invertible functions, and does so in a way where it is possible to algorithmically construct the inverse function?  It could be useful for automatically creating the deserialization of a bitstring after the serialization has been defined, or other things like that.

If the ideal case of the language containing all invertible functions isn't possible, then I'd also be interested in a fairly general purpose but not necessarily complete (wrt injective functions) grammar.

If a grammar was created that only defines injective functions then technically it is possible to construct the inverse just using a brute force search, but I would hope for a more practical and direct construction.

Comment: I think it is much more interesting question since invertible computations is the way to break energy-efficiency barrier: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing

Comment: 1) You mean, a formal grammar in _which class_ that generates invertible functions from _which domain_ using _which syntax_? 2) Since invertibility is most certainly an undecidable property (if the domain of functions isn't very restricted), there won't be a "nice" grammar. 3) Grammars are for syntax, you want to express a semantic property. The two concepts don't mix well.

Comment: It is undecidable whether a context-free grammar describes a regular language, but lots of notations exist to describe exactly the regular languages, for instance, regular grammars; it is easy to decide whether a grammar is regular. So there might be an easily decidable notation for exactly the invertible functions as well.

Comment: As well, there are polytime complete grammars despite polytime being undecidable.